# Euclidean norm of complex exponential

Tags: normed-spaces

If I have

$$\begin{aligned} \hat{\boldsymbol{a}}(z, \omega) &=e^{-i \frac{\omega}{c} z}\left(\zeta^{1 / 2} \hat{\boldsymbol{u}}(z, \omega)+\zeta^{-1 / 2} \hat{\boldsymbol{v}}(z, \omega)\right) \\ \hat{\boldsymbol{b}}(z, \boldsymbol{\omega}) &=e^{i \frac{\omega}{c} z}\left(-\zeta^{1 / 2} \hat{\boldsymbol{u}}(z, \omega)+\zeta^{-1 / 2} \hat{\boldsymbol{v}}(z, \omega)\right) \end{aligned}$$
with conditions
$$\hat{\boldsymbol{a}}^{}(z=0, \omega)=\hat{\boldsymbol{f}}(\omega), \quad \hat{\boldsymbol{b}}^{}(z=L, \omega)=\left( \begin{array}{l}{0} \\ {0}\end{array}\right)$$

How do I show

$$\left\|\hat{\boldsymbol{a}}^{}(L, \omega)\right\|^{2}+\left\|\hat{\boldsymbol{b}}^{}(0, \omega)\right\|^{2}=\|\hat{\boldsymbol{f}}(\omega)\|^{2}$$

where $$\|\hat{\boldsymbol{a}}\|=\sqrt{\left|\hat{a}_{1}\right|^{2}+\left|\hat{a}_{2}\right|^{2}}$$ denotes the Euclidean norm?

(*$\zeta, c, L ,\omega$ are purely real.*)

Comment: Which terms/factors (other than $e^{\frac{-i\omega L}{c}}$) potentially contain non-real  parts? What is $\zeta$? Note that if $\omega L/c$ is real, the initial exponential factor has magnitude $1$.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned, it is a constant.

Comment: Is it a *real* constant? And what about $\hat{u}$ and $\hat{v}$?

Comment: I will amend the question